# how do you flag a user instead of a Q or an A?

Tags: support

[This user](https://askubuntu.com/users/391572/star-os) has been posting nonsense answers on the site for the last couple of days...  How he got that many reputation points is beyond me; it just looks like he *wants* to get banned.

*How do we flag him/her/it?*  **;-)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a moderator to have a closer look on a user you flag any one post of that person for moderator intervention and explain your concern in that flag message.

Comment: Well, the mods are busy and I wanted to be nice to them, so I posted a question here where they'll see it in their own time without having to resort to multiple mod flags...  That's why the **;-)**  is in the question.  **:P**

Comment: @Fabby mods get notified of meta posts too. :P

Comment: @muru Well, yeah...  But if I was a mod, meta posts would be less urgent then a mod flag...  And one meta post is better then 10 mod flags.  **:P**